# Group data from two arrays by their first level key and form indexed subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge, mapping, associative-array

I have 2 arrays I want to merge together in a specific way.
My result(array) is maybe bad format I'm new to programming sorry for that.
I'm trying for hours to fix this with like array_merge and other array functions.

The first array have this voor example '2022-10-23' =>
and the second array have the same '2022-10-23' =>

Then I want them to merge them together on the same date.

Then the result is like this

```
array(
  '2022-10-28' => 
  array (
    array (
        '2022-10-28' => 
            'datum' => '2022-10-28',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-28' => 
            'id_therapeut' => 5,
            'client_id' => 1,
            'notitie_therapeut' => 'ff',
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-28',
    ),    
  ),
```

But when the second array have not the date inside and first array the date is empty like this only the date inside (it's not realy empty)

```
  '2022-10-25' => 
  array (
    'datum' => '2022-10-25',
  ),
```

then I want this as result

```
  array ( 
    '2022-10-25' => 
    array (
        '2022-10-25' => 
            'datum' => '2022-10-25',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-25' => 
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-25',
    ),    
  ),
```

This is the first array

```
 array (
  '2022-10-23' => 
  array (
    'id' => 10,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'notitie' => 'Mag niet !',
    'datum' => '2022-10-23',
    'user_role' => 'client',
  ),
  '2022-10-24' => 
  array (
    'id' => 11,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'notitie' => 'Mag al helemaal niet ',
    'datum' => '2022-10-24',
    'user_role' => 'client',
  ),
  '2022-10-25' => 
  array (
    'datum' => '2022-10-25',
  ),
  '2022-10-26' => 
  array (
    'id' => 15,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'notitie' => '26',
    'datum' => '2022-10-26',
    'user_role' => 'client',
  ),
  '2022-10-27' => 
  array (
    'datum' => '2022-10-27',
  ),
  '2022-10-28' => 
  array (
    'datum' => '2022-10-28',
  ),
  '2022-10-29' => 
  array (
    'datum' => '2022-10-29',
  ),
)
```

This is the second array

```
array (
  '2022-10-23' => 
  array (
    'id_therapeut' => 4,
    'client_id' => 1,
    'notitie_therapeut' => 'volgende week',
    'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-23',
  ),
  '2022-10-26' => 
  array (
    'id_therapeut' => 5,
    'client_id' => 1,
    'notitie_therapeut' => 'ff',
    'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-26',
  ),
  array (
  '2022-10-28' => 
  array (
    'id_therapeut' => 5,
    'client_id' => 1,
    'notitie_therapeut' => 'ff',
    'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-28',
  ),
)
```

This is the array(result) I want

```
    array ( 
        '2022-10-23' => 
      array (
            '2022-10-23' => 
            'id' => 10,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'notitie' => 'Mag niet !',
            'datum' => '2022-10-23',
            'user_role' => 'client',
    )
   
    array (
        '2022-10-23' => 
            'id_therapeut' => 5,
            'client_id' => 1,
            notitie_therapeut' => 'ff',
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-23',
    ),    
  ),

  array ( 
    '2022-10-24' => 
    array (
        '2022-10-24' => 
            'id' => 11,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'notitie' => 'Mag al helemaal niet ',
            'datum' => '2022-10-24',
            'user_role' => 'client',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-24' => 
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-24',
    ),    
  ),

  array ( 
    '2022-10-25' => 
    array (
        '2022-10-25' => 
            'datum' => '2022-10-25',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-25' => 
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-25',
    ),    
  ),

  '2022-10-26' => 
  array (
    array (
        '2022-10-26' => 
            'id' => 15,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'notitie' => 'ddfd',
            'datum' => '2022-10-26',
            'user_role' => 'client',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-26' => 
            'id_therapeut' => 5,
            'client_id' => 1,
            notitie_therapeut' => 'ff',
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-26',
    ),    
  ),

  array ( 
    '2022-10-27' => 
    array (
        '2022-10-27' => 
            'datum' => '2022-10-27',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-27' => 
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-27',
    ),    
  ),



  '2022-10-28' => 
  array (
    array (
        '2022-10-28' => 
            'datum' => '2022-10-28',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-28' => 
            'id_therapeut' => 5,
            'client_id' => 1,
            'notitie_therapeut' => 'ff',
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-28',
    ),    
  ),

 
    '2022-10-29' => 
    array (
        '2022-10-29' => 
            'datum' => '2022-10-29',
    ),
    array (
        '2022-10-29' => 
            'datum_therapeut' => '2022-10-29',
    ),    
  )
```

Comment: Why does `2022-10-29` have two entries in your expected result?  I'll assume this is a typo in crafting the output array.

Comment: Your second array is malformed and your desired result is inconsistently keyed on the first level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you wish to push every item (from each array) into the result array as a newly indexed entry within a subarray keyed by the date.

I don't see how this new, complex structure helps your application.  This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329). Perhaps when you presenting your data, you should just try to access both arrays by the given date instead of trying to merge the data together.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZdHcZ))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($first as $date => $row) {
    $result[$date][] = [$date => $row];
}

foreach ($second as $date => $row) {
    $result[$date][] = [$date => $row];
}
var_export($result);
```